# My queue implementation (in C)

Tags: c, queue

This is my queue implementtion in C. Feel free to ask me any questions relating to my code. Any tips or suggestions are welcome, including tips on naming/spacing/common conventions.

Queue_node, Queue, create_queue, destroye_queue, queue_push, queue_pop are meant to work with any node struct which has a member `struct Queue_node *next` and functions to create the node and destroy the node.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
/* malloc(), EXIT_SUCCESS */
#include <stdio.h>
/* fprintf */
#include <stddef.h>
/* size_t */

struct Coordinate {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct Queue_node {
    struct Queue_node *next;
};

struct Queue {
    struct Queue_node *front;
    struct Queue_node *back;

    size_t size;
};

struct Queue* create_queue(void) {

    struct Queue *created_queue = malloc(sizeof(*created_queue));

    if (created_queue == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    created_queue->back = NULL;
    created_queue->front = NULL;
    created_queue->size = 0;

    return created_queue;
}

void destroy_queue(struct Queue *input_queue, void (*delete_node)(void*)) {

    while (input_queue->front != NULL) {

        struct Queue_node *deleted_node = input_queue->front;
        input_queue->front = input_queue->front->next;
        if (delete_node != NULL) {
            delete_node(deleted_node);
        }
    }
    free(input_queue);
}

void queue_push(struct Queue *input_queue, void *input_node) {

    ++input_queue->size;

    if (input_queue->front == NULL) { // first insert

        input_queue->front = (struct Queue_node*) input_node;
        input_queue->back = (struct Queue_node*) input_node;

        return;
    }

    input_queue->back->next = (struct Queue_node*) input_node;
    input_queue->back = input_queue->back->next;
}

void* queue_pop(struct Queue* input_queue) {

    if (input_queue->front == NULL) { // empty queue
        return NULL;
    }

    --input_queue->size;

    struct Queue_node *deleted_node = input_queue->front;
    input_queue->front = input_queue->front->next;

    return deleted_node;
}

/*
nodes that are queue_pop()'d must be free()'d by caller
*/

static struct Weighted_coord_node {
    struct Queue_node *next;
    // parent property

    int weight;
    struct Coordinate coord;
    // child properties
};

static struct Weighted_coord_node* create_node(struct Coordinate coord, int weight) {

    struct Weighted_coord_node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));

    if (node == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    node->next = NULL;
    node->coord = coord;
    node->weight = weight;

    return node;
}

int main() {

    struct Queue *my_queue = create_queue();
    if (!my_queue) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct Weighted_coord_node *my_node;
    
    my_node = create_node((struct Coordinate){5,5}, 0);
    if (!my_node) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    queue_push(my_queue, my_node);

    my_node = create_node((struct Coordinate){7,7}, 2);
    if (!my_node) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    queue_push(my_queue, my_node);

    my_node = create_node((struct Coordinate){11,11}, 5);
    if (!my_node) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    queue_push(my_queue, my_node);

    while (my_node = queue_pop(my_queue)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "POP->  X: %i, Y:%i   weight: %i\n", my_node->coord.x, my_node->coord.y, my_node->weight);
        free(my_node);
    }

    destroy_queue(my_queue, free);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I rewrote the code following @vnp's suggestion. Here is the new version: [My queue implementation (in C) [V.2]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250537/my-queue-implementation-in-c-v-2)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ, noted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **DRY**. `queue_push` assigns `queue_back` to the `input_node` no matter what. Consider

  ```
    if (input_queue->front == NULL) {
        assert(input_queue->back == NULL);
        input_queue->front = input_node;
    } else {
        assert(input_queue->back != NULL);
        input_queue->back->next = input_node;
    }
    input_queue->back = input_node;
  ```

  (`assert`s are there only to clarify the logic).

  Ditto for `queue_pop`.
- Usually we don't want the client code to be aware of the containers, neither depend of them. If perchance you'd eventually decide to keep the weighted coordinates in a tree rather than a list, you'd need to redesign `struct Weighted_coord_node`, and the surrounding code. I strongly recommend to have `struct Queue_node` keeping the pointer to the actual data

  ```
    struct Queue_node {
        struct Queue_node * next;
        void * client_data;
    };
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot @vnp! I have modified my code according to your suggestions and added it into my post. Is it as you had suggested?